# Trying to remotely start a process with visible window with Python on Windows machines

Tags: python, windows, ssh, paramiko, remote-desktop

I tried to do this with WMI, but interactive processes cannot be started with it (as stated in Microsoft documentation). I see processes in task manager, but windows do not show.

I tried with Paramiko, same thing. Process visible in task manager, but no window appears (notepad for example).

I tried with PsExec, but the only case a window appears on the remote machine, is when you specify -i and it does not show normally, only through a message box saying something like *"a message arrived do you want to see it"*.

Do you know a way to start a program remotely, and have its interface behave like it would if you manually started it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the (SSH) servers run as a Windows service.

Window services run in a separate Windows session (google for *"Session 0 isolation"*). They cannot access interactive (user) Windows sessions.

Also note that there can be multiple user sessions (multiple logged in users) in Windows. How would the SSH server know, what user session to display the GUI on (even if it could)?

The message you are getting is thanks to the "Interactive Services Detection" service that detects that a service is trying to show a GUI on an invisible Session 0 and allows you to replicate the GUI on the user session.

---

You can run the SSH server in an interactive Windows session, instead as a service. It has its limitations though.

---

*In general, all this (running GUI application on Windows remotely through SSH) does not look like a good idea to me.*

*Also this question is more about a specific SSH server, rather that about an SSH client you are using. So you you include details about your SSH server, you can get better answers.*

Comment: thanks. But my question wasnt specifically about SSH. i was mentionning that i had tried SSH with no success and was looking for another route

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a way. With subprocess schtasks( the windows task scheduler). For whatever reason, when i launch a remote process with it , it starts as if i had clicked myself on the exe. For it to start with no delay, creating the task to an old date like 2012 with schtasks /Create /F and running the then named task with schtasks /Run will do the trick